# understanding copy constructor and copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, copy-assignment

According to me in case 1 copy assignment operator is used so output should be `0 68` but it is `0 87` and in case 2 it is `87 87` which is fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class numbered
{
  static int un;
public:
  int a;
  numbered (): a(un) {un++;}
  numbered(const numbered & n) : a(87){}
  numbered & operator=(const numbered) { a=68; return *this; }
};

int numbered::un=0;

void f(numbered  s){ cout<<s.a;}

int main()
{
  numbered a, b=a;
  cout << a.a << b.a;   //case 1
  f(a);f(b);        //case 2
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code *was* a mess. Please indent it better and also watch what you are declaring `public` and what `private`.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti, your edit masks the original problem the OP had with understanding his code. You mangled the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working correctly.

To get your expected result:

```
numbered a, b;
b = a;
```

Answer (score 5):

This

```
numbered a, b=a;
```

Can also be written like this:

```
numbered a, b(a);
```

This is a definition of several objects in a line. `b` is constructed here, so it's the copy c'tor that is called.